# What work contained the first mushroom trees?

Tags: history-of, science-fiction-genre, fantasy-genre

Mushroom trees are a familiar component of exotic locales, like Draenor (*Warcraft*), Morrowind (*The Elder Scrolls*), and Felucia (*Star Wars*).

The first example I know of is the *Mushroom Planet* series by Eleanor Cameron, started in 1954.

Is there an earlier example?

Comment: I'd hoped that Michael Drayton's 1627 poem _[Nymphidia](http://www.luminarium.org/editions/nymphidia.htm)_ would have had mushroom-trees, but sadly no.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jules Verne's *Voyage au centre de la Terre* or, *Journey to the Centre of the Earth* (1864) had a forest of enormous mushrooms as a feature of the interior landscape of the Earth.

> I hastened forward. I could not give any name to these singular creations. Were they some of the two hundred thousand species of vegetables known hitherto, and did they claim a place of their own in the lacustrine flora? No; when we arrived under their shade my surprise turned into admiration. There stood before me productions of earth, but of gigantic stature, which my uncle immediately named.
>
> "It is only a forest of mushrooms," said he.
>
> And he was right. Imagine the large development attained by these plants, which prefer a warm, moist climate. I knew that the *Lycopodon giganteum* attains, according to Bulliard, a circumference of eight or nine feet; but here were pale mushrooms, thirty to forty feet high, and crowned with a cap of equal diameter. There they stood in thousands. No light could penetrate between their huge cones, and complete darkness reigned beneath those giants; they formed settlements of domes placed in close array like the round, thatched roofs of a central African city.
>
> ~~*Journey to the Centre of the Earth* Ch. XXX (Malleson Translation, 1877)